# Firebase push notification not working in IOS

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

My Swift application has push notifications being sent from the app server. The notifications were coming through until a couple weeks ago. All of a sudden they stopped coming through. When I tried sending messages from the firebase console to the registration token of my iPhone , I get Unregistered Registration Token error. I also get the UnregisteredToken error when sending a message to the device from pushtry.com.
I have tried deleting the token and refreshing/recreating it in my swift code. I have also tried uninstalling/installing the application several times.
My IOS app version is 11.1.2. Xcode version 9.
I tried sending messages using the Firebase console to the old tokens where I used to be able to send notifications before and now they are also failing. I get the same error about the token being unregistered.

This problem is not happening in the android version of my code. I am able to successfully send notifications to my android device.